# npm is hanging while executing npm install command on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm-install

While installing node modules using npm install command it is hanging for long time nothing is installing. hanging at cloneCurrntTree operation. I've attached screen grab

I'm using node v6.11.5 and npm v3.10.10

Screen shot of error : npm install error:
[image]

Comment: might be network issue. give it some time

Comment: Have you tried looking at your computer resource usage? This could help point out either disk or network  activity... Also, try running it with -ddd this will output more debugging info and might help finding the exact step that hangs. You will then be able to refer your output on https://github.com/npm/npm/issues and see that you aren't the only one.